# styled components createGlobalStyle adding 10mb to entire website payload nextjs

Tags: next.js, styled-components

my font is 200kb.

When I do this it add 10MB to my entire nextjs site. What is going on.

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

import myfont from './fonts/my-font.ttf';

export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'My Font';
        src: url(${myfont}) format("truetype");
        font-style: normal; 
    }
`;
```

And then  we bundle it with rollup, with a bunch of oither components.

But when we do this

```
import { GlobalStyle } from 'component-lib/components';

export const ClientLayout = function () {
  return <GlobalStyle />;
};
```

It adds 10 mb to the payload?? What is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I'm experiencing quite similar issue.
In my case,

1. I have two `<GlobalStyle>` across the entire code of my website.
2. One of them uses `@font-face` just like you did.

So, I guess, it's because you might have 2 or more `<GlobalStyle>`, and one of them uses `@font-face`.
I'm not quite sure which one causes the problem (or perhaps both cause the problem).

The symptom in my case was this kept repeatedly creating and removing the same bundled styled components `style` tag. So, the client (the browser) kept requesting the same fonts repeatedly, causing blinking of the page and the actual font style across the whole web page kept changing (so both style and size [layout] of the page and text  kept on changing, resulting in as if the page and font are "heart-beating" like 10 times per second.)

The cause of the issue is, in my guess, due to those two parts in `createGlobalStyle` code.
(https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/main/packages/styled-components/src/constructors/createGlobalStyle.ts)

```
const ssc = useStyleSheetContext();
const theme = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
const instanceRef = React.useRef(ssc.styleSheet.allocateGSInstance(styledComponentId));
```

> 

```
const instance = instanceRef.current;

if (!__SERVER__) {
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!ssc.styleSheet.server) {
      renderStyles(instance, props, ssc.styleSheet, theme, ssc.stylis);
      return () => globalStyle.removeStyles(instance, ssc.styleSheet);
    }
  }, [instance, props, ssc.styleSheet, theme, ssc.stylis]);
}
```

In our case, seems like the `instance` or `props` or `ssc.styleSheet` kept on changing, resulting in keeps on reapeating creating and removing the bundled styled component style tag. In your case, causing the bloating up the size of the payload, and in my case, causing blinking and font kept on changing (due to repetitive requests for the same fonts.

For the reference of the symptom, this is my code.

`_app.tsx`

```
  <StyledComponentsRegistry
    showCondition={isGoogleFontsLoadedState || !!getIsSlowConnection()}
  >
    {PreloadedFontFace}
    <Styles.GlobalStyle
      isFirstRender={isFirstRender}
      screenWidth={stateScreenWidth}
      screenHeight={stateScreenHeight}
      screenAspectRatio={stateScreenAspectRatio}
      clientWidth={stateClientWidth}
      clientHeight={stateClientHeight}
      clientAspectRatio={stateClientAspectRatio}
    />
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </StyledComponentsRegistry>
```

`useSameOriginGoogleFonts.tsx`

```
export const PreloadedFontFace = createGlobalStyle<{
  fontList: Font[];
}>`
${({ fontList }) =>
fontList.map(
  (font) => `@font-face {
    font-family: "${font.family}";
    src: ${font.source};
    ${
      font.descriptors?.weight
        ? `font-weight: "${font.descriptors?.weight}";`
        : ""
    }
  }`
)}
`;
```

Edit: Added possible solution for resolving the issue and to implement the similar code in the same way [css-in-js way]. Instead of using `styled-components` `createGlobalStyle`.

Possible Solution:
Subsitute the `GlobalStyle` with `<style global jsx>` of `styled-jsx` (It's already set-up in Next.js projects)

FYI, I've added the code how I resolved the issue.

```
const PreloadedFontFaceGlobalStyle = React.memo(
  React.forwardRef<
    PreloadedFontFaceGlobalStyleRefElement,
    PreloadedFontFaceGlobalStyleProps
  >(({customProps, ...otherProps }, ref) => {
      const _fontList = [...customProps.fontList];
      return (
        <>
          {_fontList?.length !== 0 && (
            <style ref={ref} global jsx {...otherProps}>
              {`
                ${_fontList
                  .map(
                    (font) => `@font-face {
                      font-family: "${font.family}";
                      src: ${font.source};
                      ${
                        font.descriptors?.weight
                          ? `font-weight: "${font.descriptors?.weight}";`
                          : ""
                      }
                    }`
                  )
                  .join("")}
              `}
            </style>
          )}
        </>
      );
    }
  )
);
PreloadedFontFaceGlobalStyle.displayName = "PreloadedFontFaceGlobalStyle";
```